# Как отменить автоматическое выделение текста v-combobox из библиотеки Vuetify при первичном фокусе

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Можно посмотреть в доке, у них там также отрабатывает, нужно это поведение при первичном фокусе, что текст выделяется, отменить. Умные люди помогите.
Если что user-select: none  пробовал